# Disabling dynamic mapping per index in Elastic Search 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to disable the dynamic mapper for an Elastic Search index. Below is the series of queries I'm running through Kibana console to test it out.

I thought adding 'index.mapper.dynamic' should disable it at the index level right?

EDITED HERE:
I've also tried setting the dynamic property to 'false`in the type. Strangely, if I post the document then it doesn't actually update the mapping, so if check`_mapping` "filteredField" is not listed, but when I search for the document, filteredField has been indexed and is there!  -

Elastic version:

```
{
  "name": "DpVBoAZ",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid": "RX6axsbOTMatorw7s5AOXQ",
  "version": {
    "number": "5.2.0",
    "build_hash": "24e05b9",
    "build_date": "2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "6.4.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But the final GET returns this doc, note that `filteredField` is a field I added to the posted doc just to test - it should not be in the result. I also checked the mapping, and it's been dynamically added to the mapping.

What's wrong with my create index query??

```
{
  "_index": "meu_locations",
  "_type": "location",
  "_id": "12345",
  "_version": 2,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "__v": 0,
    "address1": "30 Mort Street",
    "email": "Braddon.Manager@stationeryhub.com.au",
    "faxNumber": "(02) 6122 0070",
    "geo": {
      "location": {
        "lon": 149.1317,
        "lat": -35.27433
      },
      "autogeocode": false
    },
    "identifier": "sample-store",
    "phoneNumber": "(02) 6122 0000",
    "postCode": "2612",
    "state": "ACT",
    "suburb": "Braddon",
    "title": "Hello New Title",
    "filteredField": "Hello There",
    "urlToken": "sample-store",
    "status": "Active",
    "country": "AU",
    "id": "Skcyxox6x"
  }
}
```

Search queries

```
DELETE meu_locations

PUT meu_locations
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "location": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "identifier": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "address1": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "address2": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "suburb": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "postCode": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "autogeocode": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "services": {
          "properties": {
            "specialOrder": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "assembleIt": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "wifi": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "officeFitout": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "deliverIt": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "techServices": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "parking": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "courtesyTrailer": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "extraCover": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "publishDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "expiryDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT meu_locations/location/12345
{
  "__v": 0,
  "address1": "30 Mort Street",
  "email": "Braddon.Manager@stationeryhub.com.au",
  "faxNumber": "(02) 6122 0070",
  "geo": {
    "location": {
      "lon": 149.1317,
      "lat": -35.27433
    },
    "autogeocode": false
  },
  "identifier": "sample-store",
  "phoneNumber": "(02) 6122 0000",
  "postCode": "2612",
  "state": "ACT",
  "suburb": "Braddon",
  "title": "Hello New Title",
  "filteredField": "Hello There",
  "urlToken": "sample-store",
  "status": "Active",
  "country": "AU",
  "id": "Skcyxox6x"
}

GET meu_locations/location/12345
```

Comment: I'm starting to think it's my misunderstanding of how elastic mapping works. I (somewhat sensibly) assumed if a field is not mapped, that field would not be stored in the `_source` and would just be dropped. But is it perhaps that elastic will still store the field in _source, but not save a field mapping to the index? This is what I'm observing. My only option to keep fields out  is to filter at source, and post a perfect document - what a pain. At least I can stop mistakes by setting strict to true. But would be better if the field were just dropped. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to  `"dynamic": "strict"` in mappings to disable dynamic mappings for your index.

You will need to modify your mapping part of your settings.

```
PUT meu_locations2
{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "case_insensitive_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "location": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "identifier": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "address1": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "address2": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "suburb": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "postCode": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "autogeocode": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "services": {
          "properties": {
            "specialOrder": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "assembleIt": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "wifi": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "officeFitout": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "deliverIt": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "techServices": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "parking": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "courtesyTrailer": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "extraCover": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "publishDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "expiryDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried that already. I don't want to throw an exception. I want to ignore the fields. I tried setting to false at the type level but to no avail.

Comment: i have edited my answer, if you don't want to throw exception set it to false.https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17880 https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12358

Comment: Check the updated question out. I did try that too, and even though it doesn't get mapped, the field gets indexed - and is searchable. I'm sure it's got to be a bug... I updated the script to reflect latest.